# Openstack - Change Admin password for the Dashboard

Tags: centos, dashboard, openstack

Where can I change the Admin Password for the Dasboard in Openstack?

I installed openstack with the packstack installer...

the password in the keystonerc_admin file doesn't work, too.

I use a CentOS 6.3 (and I have access to the config files)

username: admin
password: admin/password/123/etc. don't work..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOLVED

```
$ export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=$servicetoken(/etc/keystone/keystone.conf)
$ export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=$http://ipoftheserver/v2.0
```

then use this syntax to change the password

```
$ keystone user-password-update --pass <password> <user id>
```

Comment: Good answer, `keystone user-password-update --pass <password> <user id>` does the trick. If your keystonerc_admin file is accurate, and you just want to change the password, you can simply run `source /some/path/keystonerc_admin` before running `keystone user-password-update --pass <password> <user id>`.

Comment: devstack creates a user called admin. how does one find its user id so that we can change the password?

Answer (score 1):

```
openstack user password set --password <new-password> --original-password <current-admin-password>
```

Comment: source: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EH_Dpf75lKIJ:https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/105007/change-keystone-admin-pass/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu

Comment: How does this command know which user to change? e.g. devstack creates an "admin" user.  I need to change this. The ssh user is "stack".

Comment: Did work for me on Xena. John Little: The command is for the openstack CLI client: https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/xena/ When you're authenticated on the horizon web interface with the admin user top left is your user when you click on it you can choose Openstack RC file from the dropdown. After CLI client is installed use `source admin-openrc.sh` and enter your current admin password to authenticate the client.
As noted in https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/xena/cli/command-objects/user-v3.html#user-password-set it changes the password of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

referring back to:

```
 $ export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=$servicetoken(/etc/keystone/keystone.conf)
 $ export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=$http://ipoftheserver/v2.0"
```

I'm getting a bash error saying

```
"bash :syntax error near unexpected token `('"
```

I've checked my spelling and validated the syntax but I'm still unable export that service token in bash on Debian 11.;