# Openstack Dashboard default password

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

i installed Openstack from http://devstack.org/ to my Ubuntu 14.04 server 
Now i can't login to my dashboard from browser.
i tried admin admin or admin secrete

What should i do ?
Best Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Openstack - Change Admin password for the Dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768272/openstack-change-admin-password-for-the-dashboard)

Comment: I make mistake when i install openstack then i find the correct way of show password and username at there http://stackoverflow.com/a/20006869/3439922 if you still don't login to dashboard again execute  rejoin-stack.sh

Comment: For [RDO](http://rdoproject.org/install/packstack/): "The user name is admin. The password can be found in the file keystonerc_admin in the /root directory of the control node."

Comment: `/etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh` if you used the ansible script to deploy openstack.

Answer (score 8):

If you install the OpenStack using devstack, there is an file in the /devstack directory whose name is local.conf which contains all the service password that you defined during the installation.

Answer (score 3):

In case, you don't get the admin password , use the service token (admin_token) in keystone.conf and update the password of admin

```
var ADMIN_TOKEN = $(grep admin_token /etc/keystone/keystone.conf | awk '{print $3}')
export SERVICE_TOKEN=$ADMIN_TOKEN
export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://<ip>:35357/v2.0

keystone user-password-update --pass <newPassword> admin
```

Comment: I am designing horizon in flask, I want to authentication ceilometer through token based. Previously I hardcode like ` from ceilometerclient import client as ceilometer_client   cclient = ceilometer_client.get_client('2', os_username='admin', os_password='1234', os_tenant_name='demo', os_auth_url='http://10.0.2.15:5000/v2.0')
        meters=cclient.meters.list()`   How to do authetication through token based.

Answer (score 1):

The admin account's password is set in the localrc file that is part of the devstack installation. Look for ADMIN_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1):

Insert admin as a user and ADMIN for password. I hope this will work for you.