# Openstack - Change Admin password for the Dashboard? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openstack, dashboard, keystone

I am using Ubuntu 14.4 for OpenStack. When I put user and password it is not working, it shows "Invalid credentials." 
I am building Cloud Computing infrastructure by OpenStack Liberty. Where can I change the Admin Password for the Dashboard in OpenStack?

Comment: Did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768272/openstack-change-admin-password-for-the-dashboard

Comment: yes i tried it, its not working.